# Timeseries data to plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series

I have a data of dates with times and the industries happened during this dates. For example the data would be something like this:

[image: Sample example]

I want to plot the dates with as months with which industries occurred the most during this months

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried so far? your progress ?

Comment: I dont know what to do exactly, I tried ploting using pyplot it gave me an error that the values of the prime industry should be float/int

Comment: The error makes sense! On the x-axis, you have numerical data, which is fine. However, you have strings for the y-axis, which has no numeric value!

Comment: Yes I know, I need the plot to have years on X-axis and on Y- axis to have the frequency of the industry the occured the most with different colors

Comment: Use `import seaborn as sns`, and then `sns.countplot(x="date_raised", hue="primary_industry", data=df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem seems to be that you have two different data types which makes creating a graph difficult. However you can reformat the data to the proper types you want which will make creating a graph in the way you intend much easier. Something like this should work for what your wanting.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(
    [{'date_raised':pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),'primary_industry':'Real Estate'},
     {'date_raised':pd.to_datetime('2016-01-10 04:00:00'),'primary_industry':'IT Solutions'},
     {'date_raised':pd.to_datetime('2016-01-04 04:00:00'),'primary_industry':'Multimedia'},
     {'date_raised':pd.to_datetime('2016-01-05 04:00:00'),'primary_industry':'Technology'},
     {'date_raised':pd.to_datetime('2016-01-09 04:00:00'),'primary_industry':'Technology'}]
)

#Group data for monthly occurrences
result = data.sort_values('date_raised').groupby([data['date_raised'].dt.strftime('%B')])['primary_industry'].value_counts().unstack(level=1)
result.index.name = None #Remove index name "date_raised"
result.columns.names = [None] #Remove series name "primary_industry"

#Plot data
ax = result.plot(kind='bar',use_index=True,rot=1)
ax.set_xlabel('Month')
ax.set_ylabel('Total Occurrences')
plt.show()
```